# PC suddenly won't power up and boot to BIOS

Tags: hardware-failure

My PC will not power on, I cannot get to the BIOS screen. The desktop is receiving power as the pump LEDs and on-board button lights up. I have systemically removed all peripherals, GPU, RAM. I have gotten it to boot twice, once after a CMOS reset. I originally thought the problem was the battery, so I have replaced it with a new one. It booted the other time after removing GPU, but it feels like a fluke due to it not booting on afterwards even with the hardware removed. What could be the problem?

Specs:

- Mobo: Asus Z97-PRO
- CPU: i7 4790k stock
- CPU cooler: Kraken x61
- RAM: Corsair vengeance ddr3 1333MHz
- GPU: EVGA GTX 980 stock
- SSD: Adata 128GB
- PSU: EVGA Nex 650w gold rated 80+

No BIOS settings have been edited other than Hyper-V deactivation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the power supply? Although the LEDs on the motherboard could be on, the PSU may not be deliverying the necessary voltage or current. So, first I would try another Power Supply Unit. If nothing happend I think that the motherboard is the problem. If it is still with warranty take it to the computer store where you bought it.

Hope it helps.